# Is there an online way to check my appliance power usage?

Tags: appliances, energy-efficiency

I'm considering replacing my old appliances (refrigerator, washer & dryer) with a more efficient model.  Is there a website or simple method to look up their measured power usage ?

Comment: The old appliances or the new?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the appliance is [Energy Star](http://www.energystar.gov/) qualified. If it is, it should have a yellow [Energy Guidance](http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/pubs/consumer/homes/rea14.shtm) label that lists annual energy consumption.

[image]

Comment: Never seen those labels before. Must be US specific only. Would be a good idea for EU to introduce something like that.

Comment: @ppumkin You are correct, they are only in the US. Energy Star is a joint [Environmental Protection Agency](http://www.epa.gov/), [Department of Energy](http://energy.gov/) program.

Comment: We have a very similar label in Canada.  In fact, I see some US ones in some stores, so my bet is that the standard is the same.

Comment: Looks like European Union uses something called the [EU Energy Label](http://www.newenergylabel.com).

Comment: You certainly can tell it's a new label: "For details on how to calculate the index see annex VI of the Regulation (add link)" ([New EU Energy Label :: Washing machines](http://www.newenergylabel.com/sv/labelcontent/washers)). Yes, the webpage actually says "add link".

Answer (score 0):

Yea - We got a fridge the other day and we had one of these suckers on it.

[image]

This same label design is used to rate efficiently of your house insulation, water heating, , window insulation, etc...

I do not think there is an official database- [but here is something](http://www.greenconsumerguide.com/whitegoods.php); It is more up to the supplier to provide you with truthful information.